# How can I trace a Segmentation Fault in Open GL driver back to my source code?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, opengl, qml

The seg fault always appear in the function OGLDRV!DrvValidateVersion () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igdogl32.dll. However, what trigger the fault in my application is not entirely consistent. Sometimes it trigger when the user initiates the dynamic creation of a new QML Image element. Sometimes the fault is triggered when navigating a QML ListView. This leads me to suspect either a memory corruption or a race condition, but I am just guessing. I do not create or manage any threads in my own source code, but Qt automatically creates a number of threads for the application.

Unfortunately I am not experienced enough with debugging in GDB and QtCreator to collect useful information that can lead me to what part of my own source code that is resulting in this error. So my first priority is to get advice on what steps I should take to be able to trace this error back to my own source code. From the GDB backtrace I can see that when the Segfault happens there is always one Thread that originates from QQuickPixmapReader::run in qquickpixmapcache.cpp. This function in turn seems to call QThread::exec() which return with a non-zero return code (which indicates an error). But how can I find out what particular element in my application that is causing these functions to fail? Is it possible to retrieve some error code from the Open GL driver or from the Qt functions to find out more? From the backtrace it looks like QEventLoop:exec() caugth an exception, but how can I find out more about the nature of this exception?

Using Qt 5.4.0 (with QtQuick 2.2). Developing and running the application on a Dell Latitude 10 Tablet with Windows 8.1, MinGW 32 bit.

This is my first post to StackOverflow so please tell me if I need to adjust my post or add additional information. I would be happy to post source code, but I am not sure what part of my own code is relevant, since I can not find any references to my own source code files in the backtrace after the segfault. The full GDB backtrace for the most interesting threads are attached below. The Segfault happens at thread 1 and the QQuickPixmapCache is visible in Thread 16.

```
<365thread apply all backtrace full
>&"thread apply all backtrace full\n"


>~"\nThread 16 (Thread 5500.0x111c):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x77384636 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x74eed241 in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\KernelBase.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x751c91a2 in USER32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"

>~"#4  0x6b97e71c in QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents (this=0x2e5632c0, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:828\n"
>~"        nCount = 0"
>~"\n"
>~"        waitRet = 258"
>~"\n"
>~"        pHandles = {0x0 <repeats 63 times>}"
>~"\n"
>~"        processedTimers = {a = 256"
>~", s = 0"

>~", ptr = 0x2cf8e120, {array = (((omitted long array))),
>~", q_for_alignment_1 = 0"
>~", q_for_alignment_2 = 0"
>~"}"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        canWait = true"
>~"\n"
>~"        retVal = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        seenWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        d = 0x2e62dea0\n"
>~"        needWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"

>~"#5  0x6b92c77c in QEventLoop::processEvents (this=0x2cf8fe98, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:128\n"
>~"        d = 0x2e62ee88\n"
>~"#6  0x6b92ca0f in QEventLoop::exec (this=0x2cf8fe98, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:204\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 778227848"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"int QEventLoop::exec(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags)\""
>~"\n"
>~"        ref = {d = 0x2e62ee88, locker = @0x2cf8fe3c"
>~", exceptionCaught = true"
>~"}"
>~"\n"

>~"        app = 0x23fe30\n"
>~"        d = 0x2e62ee88\n"

>~"#7  0x6b7966c1 in QThread::exec (this=0x2e62d000) at thread\\qthread.cpp:503\n"
>~"        d = 0x2e62d048\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 778227848"
>~"}"
>~"\n"

>~"        eventLoop = {<QObject> = {_vptr.QObject = 0x6bbe4ee8 <vtable for QEventLoop+8>, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bb76f80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QObject>, data = 0x6bb77080 <qt_meta_data_QObject>, static_metacall = 0x6b95bac4 <QObject::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}, d_ptr = {d = 0x2e62ee88}"

>~", static staticQtMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bbc6280 <qt_meta_stringdata_Qt>, data = 0x6bbce400 <qt_meta_data_Qt>, static_metacall = 0x0, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x6bb76b0c <QObject::staticMetaObject>, stringdata = 0x6bbd9c80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QEventLoop>, data = 0x6bbd9d00 <qt_meta_data_QEventLoop>, static_metacall = 0x6b9b0884 <QEventLoop::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}"
>~"\n"
>~"        returnCode = 778229032"
>~"\n"
>~"#8  0x63298832 in QQuickPixmapReader::run (this=0x2e62d000) at util\\qquickpixmapcache.cpp:712\n"
>~"No locals.\n"
>~"#9  0x6b799238 in QThreadPrivate::start(void*)@4 (arg=0x2e62d000) at thread\\qthread_win.cpp:344\n"
>~"        thr = 0x2e62d000\n"
>~"        data = 0x2e62d0d0\n"
>~"#10 0x77270bc4 in wtoi64 () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#11 0x77270cec in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#12 0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#13 0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#14 0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#15 0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 11 (Thread 5500.0x2a8):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x77384636 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x74eed241 in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\KernelBase.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x76d114f6 in WaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x6b798e24 in qt_adopted_thread_watcher_function(void*)@4 () at thread\\qthread_win.cpp:213\n"
>~"        ret = 258"
>~"\n"
>~"        count = 3"
>~"\n"
>~"        loops = 1"
>~"\n"
>~"        handlesCopy = {d = 0x240fc900}"
>~"\n"
>~"        offset = 0"
>~"\n"
>~"        handleIndex = 0"
>~"\n"
>~"        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"DWORD qt_adopted_thread_watcher_function(LPVOID)\""
>~"\n"
>~"        threadData = 0x0\n"
>~"#5  0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#6  0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#7  0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#8  0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 9 (Thread 5500.0xc94):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x7738460e in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x74ee11a3 in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\KernelBase.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x70f4bf6a in wlanapi!WFDOpenHandleInt () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\wlanapi.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#5  0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#6  0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 8 (Thread 5500.0xe34):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x77384636 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x74eed241 in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\KernelBase.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x751c91a2 in USER32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x6b97e71c in QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents (this=0x24109d78, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:828\n"
>~"        nCount = 0"
>~"\n"
>~"        waitRet = 258"
>~"\n"
>~"        pHandles = {0x0 <repeats 63 times>}"
>~"\n"
>~"        processedTimers = {a = 256"
>~", s = 0"
>~", ptr = 0x26d0e150, {array = (((omitted long array)))
>~", q_for_alignment_1 = 1181116466064"
>~", q_for_alignment_2 = 5.8354906961964092e-312"
>~"}"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        canWait = true"
>~"\n"
>~"        retVal = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        seenWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        d = 0x24109e48\n"
>~"        needWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"#5  0x6b92c77c in QEventLoop::processEvents (this=0x26d0fec8, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:128\n"
>~"        d = 0x24109ee8\n"
>~"#6  0x6b92ca0f in QEventLoop::exec (this=0x26d0fec8, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:204\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 605068544"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"int QEventLoop::exec(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags)\""
>~"\n"
>~"        ref = {d = 0x24109ee8, locker = @0x26d0fe6c"
>~", exceptionCaught = true"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        app = 0x23fe30\n"
>~"        d = 0x24109ee8\n"
>~"#7  0x6b7966c1 in QThread::exec (this=0x24109b80) at thread\\qthread.cpp:503\n"
>~"        d = 0x24109cc0\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 605068544"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        eventLoop = {<QObject> = {_vptr.QObject = 0x6bbe4ee8 <vtable for QEventLoop+8>, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bb76f80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QObject>, data = 0x6bb77080 <qt_meta_data_QObject>, static_metacall = 0x6b95bac4 <QObject::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}, d_ptr = {d = 0x24109ee8}"
>~", static staticQtMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bbc6280 <qt_meta_stringdata_Qt>, data = 0x6bbce400 <qt_meta_data_Qt>, static_metacall = 0x0, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x6bb76b0c <QObject::staticMetaObject>, stringdata = 0x6bbd9c80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QEventLoop>, data = 0x6bbd9d00 <qt_meta_data_QEventLoop>, static_metacall = 0x6b9b0884 <QEventLoop::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}"
>~"\n"
>~"        returnCode = 651230984"
>~"\n"
>~"#8  0x6b796821 in QThread::run (this=0x24109b80) at thread\\qthread.cpp:570\n"
>~"No locals.\n"
>~"#9  0x6b799238 in QThreadPrivate::start(void*)@4 (arg=0x24109b80) at thread\\qthread_win.cpp:344\n"
>~"        thr = 0x24109b80\n"
>~"        data = 0x24109ba0\n"
>~"#10 0x77270bc4 in wtoi64 () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#11 0x77270cec in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#12 0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#13 0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#14 0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#15 0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 6 (Thread 5500.0x148):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x773845fa in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x7734941b in ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#5  0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 5 (Thread 5500.0x6b4):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x773845fa in ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x7734941b in ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#5  0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 4 (Thread 5500.0x420):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x77384ee6 in ntdll!ZwRemoveIoCompletion () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x7474a534 in Tcpip4_WSHGetWildcardSockaddr () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mswsock.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#5  0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 3 (Thread 5500.0x1488):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x77384636 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x74eed241 in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\KernelBase.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x751c91a2 in USER32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x6b97e71c in QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents (this=0x16c665f0, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:828\n"
>~"        nCount = 0"
>~"\n"
>~"        waitRet = 258"
>~"\n"
>~"        pHandles = {0x0 <repeats 63 times>}"
>~"\n"
>~"        processedTimers = {a = 256"
>~", s = 0"

>~", ptr = 0x178de0e0, {array = (((omitted long array)))
>~", q_for_alignment_1 = 0"
>~", q_for_alignment_2 = 0"
>~"}"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        canWait = true"
>~"\n"
>~"        retVal = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        seenWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        d = 0x16c64e78\n"
>~"        needWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"#5  0x6b92c77c in QEventLoop::processEvents (this=0x178dfe58, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:128\n"
>~"        d = 0x16c6b010\n"
>~"#6  0x6b92ca0f in QEventLoop::exec (this=0x178dfe58, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:204\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 382095272"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"int QEventLoop::exec(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags)\""
>~"\n"
>~"        ref = {d = 0x16c6b010, locker = @0x178dfdfc"
>~", exceptionCaught = true"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        app = 0x23fe30\n"
>~"        d = 0x16c6b010\n"

>~"#7  0x6b7966c1 in QThread::exec (this=0x16c65b38) at thread\\qthread.cpp:503\n"
>~"        d = 0x16c64f68\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 382095272"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        eventLoop = {<QObject> = {_vptr.QObject = 0x6bbe4ee8 <vtable for QEventLoop+8>, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bb76f80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QObject>, data = 0x6bb77080 <qt_meta_data_QObject>, static_metacall = 0x6b95bac4 <QObject::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}, d_ptr = {d = 0x16c6b010}"
>~", static staticQtMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bbc6280 <qt_meta_stringdata_Qt>, data = 0x6bbce400 <qt_meta_data_Qt>, static_metacall = 0x0, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x6bb76b0c <QObject::staticMetaObject>, stringdata = 0x6bbd9c80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QEventLoop>, data = 0x6bbd9d00 <qt_meta_data_QEventLoop>, static_metacall = 0x6b9b0884 <QEventLoop::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}"
>~"\n"
>~"        returnCode = 346064028"
>~"\n"
>~"#8  0x090a1512 in QQmlDebugServerThread::run (this=0x16c65b38) at debugger\\qqmldebugserver.cpp:306\n"
>~"        wrapper = 0x9434534 <(anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_debugServerInstance::innerFunction()::holder>\n"
>~"        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"virtual void QQmlDebugServerThread::run()\""
>~"\n"
>~"        connection = 0x14a08168\n"
>~"        server = 0x9434534 <(anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_debugServerInstance::innerFunction()::holder>\n"
>~"        eventLoop = {<QObject> = {_vptr.QObject = 0x16c64e78, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bb76f80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QObject>, data = 0x6bb77080 <qt_meta_data_QObject>, static_metacall = 0x6b95bac4 <QObject::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}, d_ptr = {d = 0x178dfec8}"
>~", static staticQtMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bbc6280 <qt_meta_stringdata_Qt>, data = 0x6bbce400 <qt_meta_data_Qt>, static_metacall = 0x0, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x6bb76b0c <QObject::staticMetaObject>, stringdata = 0x6bbd9c80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QEventLoop>, data = 0x6bbd9d00 <qt_meta_data_QEventLoop>, static_metacall = 0x6b9b0884 <QEventLoop::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}"
>~"\n"
>~"#9  0x6b799238 in QThreadPrivate::start(void*)@4 (arg=0x16c65b38) at thread\\qthread_win.cpp:344\n"
>~"        thr = 0x16c65b38\n"
>~"        data = 0x16c66000\n"
>~"#10 0x77270bc4 in wtoi64 () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#11 0x77270cec in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#12 0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#13 0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#14 0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#15 0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 2 (Thread 5500.0x1194):\n"
>~"#0  0x77386ce4 in ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x77384636 in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x74eed241 in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\KernelBase.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x751c91a2 in USER32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x6b97e71c in QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents (this=0x16bb17d8, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:828\n"
>~"        nCount = 0"
>~"\n"
>~"        waitRet = 258"
>~"\n"
>~"        pHandles = {0x0 <repeats 63 times>}"
>~"\n"
>~"        processedTimers = {a = 256"
>~", s = 0"
>~", ptr = 0x16eae150, {array = (((omitted long array)))
>~", q_for_alignment_1 = 0"
>~", q_for_alignment_2 = 0"
>~"}"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        canWait = true"
>~"\n"
>~"        retVal = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        seenWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"        d = 0x16bb17f8\n"
>~"        needWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = false"
>~"\n"
>~"#5  0x6b92c77c in QEventLoop::processEvents (this=0x16eafec8, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:128\n"
>~"        d = 0x16bb1898\n"
>~"#6  0x6b92ca0f in QEventLoop::exec (this=0x16eafec8, flags=...) at kernel\\qeventloop.cpp:204\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 381359752"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"int QEventLoop::exec(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags)\""
>~"\n"
>~"        ref = {d = 0x16bb1898, locker = @0x16eafe6c"
>~", exceptionCaught = true"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        app = 0x23fe30\n"
>~"        d = 0x16bb1898\n"

>~"#7  0x6b7966c1 in QThread::exec (this=0x16bb15f0) at thread\\qthread.cpp:503\n"
>~"        d = 0x16bb1648\n"
>~"        locker = {val = 381359752"
>~"}"
>~"\n"
>~"        eventLoop = {<QObject> = {_vptr.QObject = 0x6bbe4ee8 <vtable for QEventLoop+8>, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bb76f80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QObject>, data = 0x6bb77080 <qt_meta_data_QObject>, static_metacall = 0x6b95bac4 <QObject::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}, d_ptr = {d = 0x16bb1898}"
>~", static staticQtMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x0, stringdata = 0x6bbc6280 <qt_meta_stringdata_Qt>, data = 0x6bbce400 <qt_meta_data_Qt>, static_metacall = 0x0, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}, static staticMetaObject = {d = {superdata = 0x6bb76b0c <QObject::staticMetaObject>, stringdata = 0x6bbd9c80 <qt_meta_stringdata_QEventLoop>, data = 0x6bbd9d00 <qt_meta_data_QEventLoop>, static_metacall = 0x6b9b0884 <QEventLoop::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)>, relatedMetaObjects = 0x0, extradata = 0x0}"
>~"}}"
>~"\n"
>~"        returnCode = 384499464"
>~"\n"
>~"#8  0x0908d812 in QQmlThreadPrivate::run (this=0x16bb15f0) at qml\\ftw\\qqmlthread.cpp:141\n"
>~"No locals.\n"
>~"#9  0x6b799238 in QThreadPrivate::start(void*)@4 (arg=0x16bb15f0) at thread\\qthread_win.cpp:344\n"
>~"        thr = 0x16bb15f0\n"
>~"        data = 0x16bb16d0\n"
>~"#10 0x77270bc4 in wtoi64 () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#11 0x77270cec in msvcrt!_beginthreadex () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcrt.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#12 0x76d117ad in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\kernel32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#13 0x7737226c in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#14 0x77372245 in ntdll!RtlTryAcquireSRWLockShared () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#15 0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"


>~"\nThread 1 (Thread 5500.0x9c4):\n"
>~"#0  0x59f754c0 in OGLDRV!DrvValidateVersion () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\igdogl32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#1  0x0023cec4 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#2  0x59f6e8c5 in OGLDRV!DrvValidateVersion () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\igdogl32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#3  0x299b8d08 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#4  0x59f8abc0 in OGLDRV!DrvValidateVersion () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\igdogl32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#5  0x299b8d08 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#6  0x59f8b1e1 in OGLDRV!DrvValidateVersion () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\igdogl32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#7  0x299b8d08 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#8  0x59f8be5a in OGLDRV!DrvValidateVersion () from C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\igdogl32.dll\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#9  0x00000de1 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>~"#10 0x00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"No symbol table info available.\n"
>365^done
```

Comment: We had exactly the same issue, coming from some graphic driver issues. Switching QT_OPENGL to angle is a good workaround for this issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I continued my invesigations into this issue, since I recieved no answer to my question. I realise that the lack of answer might be because of my question being formulated in a verbose and vague manner. I have not managed to find the reason for the Segmentation fault. However, I wanted to share some of the things that I have learned about debugging Qt and Open GL. Maybe this could be of some help for other Open GL rookies like me.

After several days of struggling I had still not managed to get useful error messages from the QtCreator debugger (GDB). I started looking for alternatives and it turned out that gDEBugger was highly useful for this. Here is what I did step by step:

**1. Deployment of my application**

To be able to debug with an external debugger I had to do a complete deployment of my application on my machine (Windows 8.1 32 bit). I never had to do this before, since I only run and debug my application directly through QtCreator. The deployment process turned out to be quite trivial in my case, but I will explain it nevertheless: I used the tool windeployqt.exe that is shipped with the Qt install binary for Windows. Located at QTDIR/min gw491_32/bin on my machine. First I build my application (debug build) thorugh QtCreator. After this I run the following console command "windeployqt.exe path-to-application-binary". It requires that the Qt bin folder is added to the machine's PATH Environment Variable. To include external QML-files, see the documentation for windeployqt.

**2. Download and install gDEBugger**

**3. Start debugging**

Now you can fire up gDEbugger. Create a new project and choose your application binary. The gDEBugger documentation is easy to follow and I recommend it. In the same direcory there should be all the DLL's and other files added during deployment. To provide the most useful information you should have built and deployed a debug version of your application. Add breakpoints for all errors and press run (F5). This allowed me to find several OpenGL errors, and hopefully I will evetually manage to understand how to get rid of the errors as well. Also pause the debugging and take a look at the Textures and Buffers loaded in memory. I found an unknown texture that might be the cause of my problems. Good luck debugging!